# Animating UIView and Mask

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView which is basically a mole. I want this mole to pop out of a hole. So actually what I have in mind is that I will create a mole some points below the hole and have a mask over it so and then animate up the image view so it looks like its popping out of hole. So following the thought , I had made written down this code :

```
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    CGRect maskRect = _moleIcon.frame;
    CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(maskRect, NULL);
    maskLayer.path = path;
    CGPathRelease(path);
    _moleIcon.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^(void){
        _moleIcon.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 50);
    }];
```

but the problem, is that it seems that the mask itself is moving with the actual UIImageView. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Why not just use 2 views? One for the mask and one for the mole?

Comment: Can you please explain that in detail? I am not sure how can I acheive this using two UIViews.

Answer (score 0):

try to use 2 UIViews, just maskView should be bring to front:

```
[superview bringSubviewToFront:maskView];
```

and set background color and alpha property for mask view,

```
maskView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
maskView.alpha = 0.8;
```

and now you can move 2 view directly.

but better is to add 2 view to other view - container, and rotate this one view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but then I will have a black view in the game. I dont want that. In the image I had written mask on the black image which specifically means that part is not to be seen on screen. It just serves the purpose of hiding whats underneath it.

Comment: Are you suggesting me to set the view color to clear? Are you aware that if you set a color to clear it will show whats behind it. Thats very basic knowledge about UIView clear color.

Comment: Are you aware, that if you set background to clear and present UIImage on it, it will show you image, without rectangle background?

Comment: But I dont need to show two UIImages. I only only UIImage that is a mole to disappear before a mask and to pop out of it. The black part in the image in the question is labelled mask, that is we dont want it to be seen on the screen. I am half way through finding the solution and will post the answer here when done. Thanks for your help though! :)